# Find object by its property in array of objects with AngularJS way

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I have a array like below

```
var myArray = [{'id':'73','name':'john'},{'id':'45','name':'Jass'}, etc.]
```

Now I have an `id` 73 how to select this particular object from the array. I see I can do this in jQuery easily with [**grep**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/) Is there any **angular way** of doing this?

Since most user developing app with angular always get data from array of objects(mostly for table) there should be a helper function for this?

So that I can change the data of the row with the ID of the row by updating the array of object.

I don't want to bind this in view. I want to manipulate the data and update the data withing function.

For Example. I have a table listing. If end user edit a row from the table I have the ID of the object so after end user hit save, I need to update the array and then back to table listing.

Comment: @JaredSmith I'm looking for any angular helper function(like angular.isNumber) for this, not javascript default array object methods.

Comment: that makes no sense at all. Why would you need a framework helper function to replace a native method supported all the way back to IE 9? Unless you give a reason otherwise, it just comes across as an XY problem http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem.

Comment: I can understand why you wouldn't want to include jquery if you're already using angular, but `.filter` is both native and well-supported. If you can give a compelling reason why angular, and angular alone, **must** be used to solve this problem I'll retract the close vote.

Comment: OP wanted an [tag:angularjs] answer. The target dupe didn't answer the question. Just like a jQuery solution doesn't answer a [tag:javascript] question.

Comment: __[This question is being discussed on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337229/can-we-do-something-how-do-i-do-x-in-angular-react-frameworky)__

Comment: @JaredSmith OP answered you, but in a comment on the accepted answer: "I was thinking to apply the filter only in view mode with markup". When one doesn't specify their requirements fully in the question, one tends to waste a lot of other people's time.  That's kinda rude to people who are trying to help you.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

you can use angular's `filter`
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

in your controller:

```
$filter('filter')(myArray, {'id':73})
```

or in your HTML

```
{{ myArray | filter : {'id':73} }}
```

Comment: Thanks +1 I was thinking to apply the filter only in view mode with markup, thanks for the idea to use it in controller too.

Comment: Just a note to fellow learners, We need to pass `$filter`in our controller in order to use this method.

Comment: Worth noting that the above code will filter based upon the ID being a substring. So filtering on an id of 73 would also find 733, 4573, 173 etc. To get a strict comparison you must pass a third comparator parameter of 'true' as per the docs.

Comment: Is there any way to store the result in HTML? I need that filter result in some loop. so this will reduce my filter process in each loop iteration. BTW i am new to angular. Thanks.

Answer (score 48):

How about plain JavaScript? [More about `Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```js
var myArray = [{'id': '73', 'name': 'john'}, {'id': '45', 'name': 'Jass'}]

var item73 = myArray.filter(function(item) {
  return item.id === '73';
})[0];

// even nicer with ES6 arrow functions:
// var item73 = myArray.filter(i => i.id === '73')[0];

console.log(item73); // {"id": "73", "name": "john"}
```

Comment: Thanks +1 for the help. I already saw the JavaScript filter method, I was looking for angular way.

Comment: How about using `FIND` instead?

Comment: @Dementic `find` support was still pretty fresh in Chrome when the answer was written, and for example is not available in IE at all. `filter` on the other hand is.

Comment: IE ? What is that ? :)

Answer (score 12):

For complete `M B` answer, if you want to access to an specific attribute of this object already filtered from the array in your HTML, you will have to do it in this way:

`{{ (myArray | filter : {'id':73})[0].name }}`

So, in this case, it will print `john` in the HTML.

Regards!

Answer (score 1):

The solucion that work for me is the following

```
$filter('filter')(data, {'id':10})
```